# what is a good microphone for a real time voice activated switch?

Tags: arduino, microphone, hardware

My team and I are trying to build a voice-activated switch. We are trying to look for a good microphone that can pick up sound (as an analog input, no digital input) and it should also work at a distance of 3-4 meters (ex: it should work within a room) away from the switch board.

We have had success with digital inputs in various microphones at a distance of 20cm (the LED turns on when it picks up loud sound). However, when we try to use analog input, no matter how much we tune the mic, the LED does not work in accordance with the sound in the environment

Can anyone suggest a good model of microphone for the above-specified details?

We did some research and we found that MEMs microphone could be ideal for this, however, there aren't many resources for us to refer to (in terms of how to properly implement it). If anyone has any helpful sources, please do suggest them.

Comment: The problem will almost certainly be in how you are conditioning the analogue signal.

Answer (score 1):

What's your budget?  There are some cheap ($50) microphones with parabolic reflectors for bird listening. But quite directional. Or you could get a larger version like used on the sidelines of sports events for about $3000.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing a ton of information

Electret elements are cheap, MEMS mics are small, dynamic mics sound warm, etc., but *any* microphone will pick up the ambient sound 3 m away; that is what microphones do.  However, no microphone element by itself can separate what you want to hear from what you don't want, and at 3-4 m, almost everything will be what you don't want.

Without getting into complex filters in a DSP, you are limited to bandpass filtering to enhance the vowel energy in syllables.  That is a loooong way from what your brain does to extract speech from noise.

There are basic sound sensor / detector modules on ebay.  Here is one for $1.39:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/353604593291?hash=item525479e68b:g:QWMAAOSwc1FXYCwi

Here is one with a voice filter for $5.99:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/363394557689?hash=item549c00e6f9:g:zD0AAOSwNk1gnQA~